# Calcular cantidad de paginas en DataGridView y MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en MySQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_Listado_pr`(IN cTexto varchar(100),pagina int,registros int, OUT cantRegistros int ,cantPaginas int)
begin 
declare inicio int;              

declare fin int;
 
 set inicio=(pagina - 1) * registros +1;
 set fin=(inicio + registros -1)/pagina;
IF (cTexto!="") THEN 

SELECT 
    
    a.codigo_pr,
    a.codigo_an,
    a.codigo_barra,
    a.descripcion_pr,
    b.descripcion_ma,
    c.descripcion_um,
    d.descripcion_ca,
    a.stock_min,
    a.stock_max,
    a.codigo_ma,
    a.codigo_um,
    a.codigo_ca,
    a.pu_venta
FROM
    tb_productos a
        INNER JOIN
    tb_marcas b ON a.codigo_ma = b.codigo_ma
        INNER JOIN
    tb_unidades_medidas c ON a.codigo_um = c.codigo_um
        INNER JOIN
    tb_categorias d ON a.codigo_ca = d.codigo_ca
WHERE
    a.estado = 1
        AND (UPPER(TRIM(a.descripcion_pr)) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(TRIM(cTexto)), '%')
        OR (a.codigo_barra = cTexto))
ORDER BY a.codigo_pr
LIMIT inicio,fin; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() into cantRegistros;
set cantPaginas=cantRegistros/registros;
ELSE
 select a.codigo_pr,   
    a.codigo_an,
  a.codigo_barra,
  a.descripcion_pr,    
  b.descripcion_ma,    
  c.descripcion_um,    
  d.descripcion_ca,    
  a.stock_min,    
  a.stock_max,    
  a.codigo_ma,    
  a.codigo_um,    
  a.codigo_ca,  
  a.pu_venta  
 from tb_productos             a       
 inner join tb_marcas           b on a.codigo_ma=b.codigo_ma    
 inner join tb_unidades_medidas c on a.codigo_um=c.codigo_um    
 inner join tb_categorias       d on a.codigo_ca=d.codigo_ca    
 where a.estado=1  
order by a.codigo_pr LIMIT inicio,fin; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() into cantRegistros;
set cantPaginas=cantRegistros/registros;
END IF;
end
```

En el Workbench es decir en el gestor funciona perfecto llamando al procedimiento.
El caso es que tengo un datagridView en C# y quiero obtener el total de registros que trae la consulta  y luego obtener el numero de paginas resultantes.

entonces tengo en c# que recuperar la tabla ylos dos valores de out

```
              public (DataTable Tabla,int paginar,int cantidadr) Listado_pr(string cTexto,int pagina,int cantidad)
        {
            MySqlDataReader Resultado;
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection SQLCon = new MySqlConnection();

            try
            {
                SQLCon = Conexion.getInstancia().CrearConexion();
                MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand("USP_Listado_pr", SQLCon);
                Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("cTexto", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cTexto;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("pagina", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = pagina;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("registros", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cantidad;

                Comando.Parameters.Add("cantRegistros", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                Comando.Parameters["cantRegistros"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("cantPaginas", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                Comando.Parameters["cantPaginas"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                SQLCon.Open();
                Resultado = Comando.ExecuteReader();
                Tabla.Load(Resultado);
                int paginar = Convert.ToInt32(Comando.Parameters["cantPaginas"].Value);
                int cantidadr= Convert.ToInt32(Comando.Parameters["cantRegistros"].Value);
                return (Tabla,paginar,cantidad);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (SQLCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) SQLCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

En el llamado a la funcion tengo:

```
        private void Listado_pr(string cTexto,int pagina,int cantidad)
        {
      
            try
            {
               
                (DataTable productos,int pr, int cr) = N_Productos.Listado_pr(cTexto,pagina,cantidad);
                Dgv_principal.DataSource = productos;
               // label21.Text = cr.ToString();

                this.Formato_pr();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Pero obtengo un error de conversion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No has puesto codigo de C# aqui solamente tenemos la consulta SQL. De todas maneras, para hacer el calculo simplemente debes coger el numero total de lineas que trae la consulta (con un COUNT lo tendrias solucionado) y dividirlo por el numero de elementos por pàgina (redondeando hacia arriba para los picos) y ya tendrias el numero de paginas

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta, ya logre hacer el sp.

Comment: No se como se hace, pero seguro no es un executereader... eso devuelve las filas para que las puedas trabajar, pero se olvida de los parametros de salida... executenonquery te va a devolver los parametros, pero no te va a devolver el resultado de la query... no se que hay en el medio, o si tenes que devolver las dos cosas...

Comment: igual, lo que estas calculando en el SP, se puede calcular tambien en el programa... la cantidad de registros la tenes en los dos lados...

Comment: no quise hacerlo en el programa para no traer todos los registros y traer solo la pagina..y si estoy averiguando como se podria hacer